# Is this a good way to assign a Solve result to a function?

Tags: assignment

My code:

```
(* v1 = ripple minimum, v2 = ripple maximum *)
Clear[ripple, v1, v2, dc, rc, t0]; 
r = Solve[{v1 + (1 - v1) (1 - E^(-dc t0/rc)) == v2 && v2 E^(-(1 - dc) t0/rc) == v1 &&
       ripple == v2 - v1}, {v1, v2, ripple}]
```

which returns

[image]

Now I wanted to assign the expression for ripple to a function, and after a couple of failed attempts I came up with this:

```
ripple[t0_, rc_, dc_] := Evaluate[First[r][[3,2]]]
```

This works, but I don't know if this is good practice, and I don't want to get bad habits. So, what's the "right" way to do this?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5319771/618728

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - Thanks for the link. Admittedly, a rival site :-), but they seem friendly enough :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`SetDelayed` ( **: =** ) suppose to delay evaluation of the right hand side, but you enforce it anyway by `Evaluate`. So you are doing sorts of redundant things - see comment by @Mr.Wizard . To get a hang of the topic read tutorial [**Immediate and Delayed Definitions**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ImmediateAndDelayedDefinitions.html) . In general I think it is more natural to base extraction of needed formula on the variable name rather than on indexes of solution list. It also improves code clarity:

```
ripple[t0_, rc_, dc_] = First[ripple /. r]
```

I hope your "shudder" of `/.` can be cured by [**Applying Transformation Rules**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ApplyingTransformationRules.html) ;-)

Comment: Thanks. I guess I really should dive into that ReplaceAll... [shudders]

Comment: Any comments on my using `SetDelayed` instead of `Set`? (It looks like I can't use `SetDelayed` with the `ReplaceAll`)

Comment: @stevenvh The form:  `func[x_, y_] := Evaluate[ . . . ]` serves no purpose.  Symbols `x` and `y` are not localized with this form as `Evaluate` causes evaluation before that mechanism activates.  Use `=` as shown.  (ps what's wrong with `/.` ?)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - Oh, nothing wrong with it. On the contrary: when I look at some code it seems really powerful. I just can't get the hang of it completely yet. Sometimes a bit cryptic. I guess it will come "with time and sandwiches", as we say in Dutch :-)

Comment: @stevenvh I updated answer a bit